# how to select words in ms word searching for tags

Tags: c#, search, ms-word

I got a word document which I open from c# code (see code below). The word document could contain whatever a word document can (tables, pictures and whatsoever).
Enough information about the document. What I want is to search for a specific mark and then select the whole word.

EXAMPLE:

This could be text before a word which I want to find,
!#Command1 this could be text after a word I want to find
!#Command2 maybe a picture here or something
!#Command3

I want to select the 3 words (!#Command1, !#Command2, !#Command3) and add them to a list.

CODE:

```
        public List<string> getListOfCommands()
        {
            List<string> commandList = new List<string>();
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            object fileName = ofd.FileName;

            Word.Application wapp = GetWordApp();
            var document = wapp.Documents.Open(fileName);

            object findText = "!#"; //Commands tag
            wapp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
            if(wapp.Selection.Find.Execute(findText))
            {
                //Add the !#Command to a list here
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return commandList;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some more time on it and found a workaround for the problem by addind and endTag to the commands.

The new code:

```
public List<string> getListOfCommands()
        {
            List<string> commandList = new List<string>();

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            object fileName = ofd.FileName;

            Word.Application wapp = GetWordApp();
            var document = wapp.Documents.Open(fileName);
            var range1 = document.Range();
            var range2 = document.Range();

            string findTextStart = "!#"; //Commands tagStart
            string findTextEnd = "#!"; //Commands tagEnd
            wapp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();

            range1.Find.Execute(findTextStart);
            while (range1.Find.Found)
            {
                if (range1.Text.Contains(findTextStart))
                {
                    range2.Find.Execute(findTextEnd);
                    if (range1.End < range2.Start)
                    {
                        Word.Range temprange = document.Range(range1.End, range2.Start);
                        commandList.Add(temprange.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commandList.Add("Error - Are you missing a start or end tag?");
                    }
                }
                range1.Find.Execute(findTextStart);
            }
            return commandList;
        }
```